# Access denied when adding key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE using bat file, adding to HKEY_CURRENT_USER works fine

Tags: windows-10, command-line, permissions, batch-file, windows-registry

I need to add a new registry key to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRunTime\AllowedCOMCLSIDs.

I tried running a following bat script:

```
@echo off 
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\AllowedCOMCLSIDs\NewKey" /f /ve
PAUSE
```

What I got in return was an access denied message, tried doing the same by launching a cmd.exe as an administrator but got the same information. I only have one account on this computer and it has the admin rights.

I also tried running this script to see if it can add that key to a different directory under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and so I ran this script:

```
@echo off 
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NewKey /f /ve
PAUSE
```

And that script was completed successfully.

Any idea how can I make the first one run properly as well? I've searched through multiple questions, threads and video tutorials showing modifications of users' groups properties but it doesn't really apply in this case, nothing changes since I already have all the rights assigned.

I'd be grateful for your help.

Edit: Ok, thanks everyone for your comments, I didn't have a clue that you can change the permissions for keys as well. Had to change the owner from SYSTEM to my account and then grant full permissions for those accounts and now the .bat script completes successfully.

Additional question - is it possible to change the owner of a given key file and grant the required permissions all in a single .bat file?

Comment: Having admin rights is not necessarily enough to access certain sensitive areas of the system. Right click the parent key and check the permissions and see if this path is restricted to system or trustedinstaller, etc. make sure if actually provides `administrators`, `users` or `everyone` with write access. Anti-virus software may also produce results like this.

Comment: @Appleoddity You might as well make that a full answer instead of a comment. That is exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the ACL for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\AllowedCOMCLSIDs\` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Didn't know that the keys also have the owners and you can grant permissions to change them - TIL. Thanks for help! Any idea if it's possible to change those owners and permissions using a bat file as well? Would like to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

The key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` contains user data that is mostly entirely
accessible and modifiable by the current user.

The key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE contains system-wide data, some of it very
sensible, so modifying it usually requires administrator permissions.
However, some data is crucial for Windows to work correctly,
so the permissions for those key are exclusively kept by the
TrustedInstaller account. An administrator account does not have
the permissions to modify data owned by the TrustedInstaller account.

This is exactly the situation with the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\AllowedCOMCLSIDs`,
whose permissions are as follows:

[image]

The key is owned by TrustedInstaller, which is the only account that
has full control of the key.

In short - you cannot modify this key. Windows will not allow it.

You need to find a way of doing what you're trying to do using some
built-in Windows application that has the right permissions.
I suggest detailing your underlying problem in a new question,
asking for a solution that doesn't require modifying
registry keys that are reserved by Windows.

Comment: The author could change the permissions of the key, in theory, but it's not advised and there is a good reason that particular key is protected.

Comment: @Ramhound I just did that, changed the permissions which allowed the script to do its job. Thanks for help!

Comment: That required taking ownership of a vital Windows registry key, which might later cause unpredictable side-effects.